# Google Cloud Memorystore (Redis) ETIMEDOUT in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, redis

Im writing a NodeJS app and trying to connect to GCPs Redis MemoryStore, but I'm getting the `ETIMEDOUT 10.47.29.131:6379` error message.  The `10.47.29.131` corresponds to the `REDISHOST`. I'm trying to reach the server by it's internal private IP.

While the app works locally with a local Redis installed, it does not when deployed to the GCP AppEngine.

My GCP-Setup

- Redis instance running at location europe-west3-a
- Created a connector under "Serverless VPC access" which is in europe-west3
- Redis and the VPC-connector are on the same network "default".
- App Engine running in europe-west

Redis isntance:
[image]

VPC-connector:
[image]

The app.yml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

automatic_scaling:

// or this but without env: flex (standard)
vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/project-ID/locations/europe-west/connectors/connector-name"

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: project-ID:europe-west3:name

env_variables:
  REDISHOST: '10.47.29.131'
  REDISPORT: '6379'

// removed this when trying without env: flex (standard)
network:
  name: default
  session_affinity: true
```

I followed these instructions to set everything up: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-standard

Digging deeper, I found: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access where they mention something about permissions and `serverless-vpc-access-images`, and while trying to follow the instructions: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/restricting-image-access#trusted_images I couldn't find "Define trusted image projects." anywhere

What am I missing here?

Comment: Had the same issue, be sure to add permission for "Compute Engine VM" to the service account you're using for deployment of the app.

Comment: The account I'm deploying with, has the Owner-permission on the whole project. Shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: This is an IP addressing issue and not an IAM issue - Owner does not help with IP addressing problems. More details on what the address is (private, public, same VPC, etc).

Comment: @ad_on_is afaik that's not enough. The account I'm using is also owner, and yet I had to add the Compute Engine privileges there...

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I added "Compute Admin" to both, the owner service-account and to the appengine-service-account, which had no effect.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm trying to reach the redis-server via its private IP-address, which is shown on the memorystore-instance detail-page.

Comment: Is the VPC connector attached to the Redis instance's authorized VPC network?

Comment: Make sure you are addressing MemoryStore correctly. Review the examples in this link: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-standard

Comment: @JohnHanley both are on the "default" network. The link you provided is exactly the one I followed for setting everything up. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access mentions something about permissions and `serverless-vpc-access-images`, and while trying to follow the instructions: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/restricting-image-access#trusted_images I can't find "Define trusted image projects." anywhere

Comment: I've attached some screenshots of the redis-instance and vpc-connector configuration, hope that helps in any way.

Comment: The example shows REDISHOST as localhost, your question shows an IP address.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't understand what you mean? REDISHOST is set in the app.yaml to `<REDIS_IP>` in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Well, turns out, the problem was the region I've selected for the Redis instance.

From [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/regions):

> **Important**: In order to connect to a Memorystore for Redis instance, the connecting client **must** be located within the **same region** as the instance.
>
> A region is a specific geographical location where you can run your resources. Each region is subdivided into several zones.
>
> > For example, the us-central1 region in the central United States has zones us-central1-a, us-central1-b, us-central1-c, and us-central1-f.

Althouh the documentation clearly says, that AppEngine and Memorystore have to be in the same region, my assumption on what regions actually are, was false.

When I created the AppEngine, I created it in `europe-west`, which is the same as `europe-west1`. On the other hand, when I created the redis instance, I used `europe-west3`, with the assumption that `west3` is the same region as `west`, which is not.

Since the AppEngines region cannot be changed, I created another redis-instance in `europe-west1` and now everything works.

So, the redis region must be exactly the same as the AppEngine region. `region1` is the same as `region`, but `region2` or `region3` are not the same as `region`.

Comment: There is no region `europe-west1`

Comment: When creating a redis instance, there is a region europe-west1.

Comment: yes, you are right `europe-west` for App Engine is `europe-west1` for Redis, confusing